# How will users Sync their Media with Windows Phone devices?

Tags: sync, windows-8

Zune Desktop App syncs media files from their PC to their Windows Phone devices.

With Windows 8, Zune Brand disappears. How does syncing work then?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://www.gmanetwork.com/news/story/278997/scitech/technology/microsoft-s-zune-switched-off-xbox-music-now-online), they have replaced Zune Music by Xbox Music, this is even listed on their site itself, you can see it on http://www.zune.net. The same article also mentions:

> Support for Zune devices can be accessed in the Zune support section on [xbox.com](http://xbox.com)